# exists() function not finding any documents in Firestore Security Rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

So I have a `followers` collection and a `users` collection. Creating a doc in the `followers` collection with a certain ID requires a doc to exist with the same ID in the `users` collection.

So, in the security rules, I check for the existence of that document.

```
match /followers/{followers} {

  function loggedInUserMatching() {
    return (request.auth != null) && (request.auth.uid == followers);
  }

  function userExistsAndLoggedIn() {
    return loggedInUserMatching() && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid));
  }

  allow create, delete: if userExistsAndLoggedIn();
}
```

In my tests, I try to create a doc in `followers` without the corresponding doc in the `users` collection. This should fail.

```
const database = testEnv.authenticatedContext('user1').firestore();

let testFollowersDoc = database.collection("followers").doc("user1");

expect(assertFails(testFollowersDoc.set({followers: []}))).resolves.toBeDefined();
```

Then, I create the doc in the `users` collection and then try to create the doc in `followers` again. This should succeed, but it always fails.

```
const testUserDoc = database.collection("users").doc("user1");

testUserDoc.set({about: "Wow", following: []});

expect(assertSucceeds(testFollowersDoc.set({followers: []}))).resolves.toBeUndefined();
```

The `create` rule for the `users` collection is correct and the document is actually created. I can access its data and verify it exists. But in my security rules, the `exists()` function always returns `false`, so the permission is denied and the document is not created.

What could be the cause of this? Am I using the `exists()` function incorrectly? Or am I not creating the document properly in my test?

I've been trying to solve this for a long time so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/wcpq4o/exists_function_not_finding_any_documents_in/

Answer (score 0):

These lines are asynchronous and should have `await`.

```
expect(assertFails(await testFollowersDoc.set({followers: []}))).resolves.toBeDefined();

expect(assertSucceeds(await testFollowersDoc.set({followers: []}))).resolves.toBeUndefined();
```